# How to get accurate data for a date range not greater than a given one in a periodically updating data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

i have a database which has some units which report in at regular intervals. I want a query where I can see units that have not logged after a certain date.

```
select distinct FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.AgencyVehicle.AgencyVehicleName from FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.AgencyVehicle
inner join FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.VehicleLocation
on FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.AgencyVehicle.AgencyVehicleKey = FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.VehicleLocation.AgencyVehicleKey
where FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.VehicleLocation.GPSLocationDate < '2013-01-01'
and FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.AgencyVehicle.TermDate is NULL
order by AgencyVehicleName
```

NOW IT SHOWS ME VEHICLES WHO ALSO HAVE LOGS AFTER "2013-01-01", BECAUSE THEY ALSO HAVE LOGS BEFORE AND AFTER THIS DATE

HOW CAN I EXCLUDE NAMES FROM BEING SHOWN WHICH ALSO HAVE DATE LOGS AFTER THAT >?

Comment: Please, correct your uppercase text - use proper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `distinct` to `group by`.  Then add a `having` clause.  You are looking for the *largest* date being before the cutoff:

```
select FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.AgencyVehicle.AgencyVehicleName
from FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.AgencyVehicle inner join
     FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.VehicleLocation
     on FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.AgencyVehicle.AgencyVehicleKey = FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.VehicleLocation.AgencyVehicleKey
where FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.AgencyVehicle.TermDate is NULL
group by FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.AgencyVehicle.AgencyVehicleName
having MAX(FSS_LIVE_50.dbo.VehicleLocation.GPSLocationDate) < '2013-01-01'
order by AgencyVehicleName;
```

Judicious use of aliases would also make your query much more readable.